# Karate Robot - How to access start menu and Windows search

Tags: karate

I was playing around with Karate Robot, really cool.
I got it running and could follow the feature which opened calc.exe

Is there a way to access the Windows Start menu and / or the Search button mainly on the taskbar.

The use case I am trying to reach with Karate Robot is to check if programs are found via the search and found in the Windows start menu (also under specific folders).
And them click on the app and do some basic logon or some basic actions.

Thanks so much for your suggestions.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI automation is not easy :) I suggest you install `Inspect.exe`, there are some tips here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide#windows-tips

Anyway, this works for me on Windows 10. To click the `Start` button:

```
* click('/root/pane{Taskbar}/{Start}')
```

And to do a search, these 3 lines did it for me and even opened `notepad`. Because a click on the `Start` button automatically sets focus to the search box:

```
* click('/root/pane{Taskbar}/{Start}')
* input('notepad')
* input(Key.ENTER)
```

Comment: Yeah, splendid this works for me too. You made it crazy simple.

The search button is quite special...
* click('/root/pane{Taskbar}/{Type here to search}')